# Referencing recursive types A <-> B in TypeScript which contain generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, recursive-type

I have this code in TypeScript:

```js
type DormNodePredicate = DormEdge | (() => DormNode<DormNodePredicateRecord>);
interface DormNodePredicateRecord {
  [key: string]: DormNodePredicate;
}

export class DormNode<DNPR extends DormNodePredicateRecord> {
  constructor(public preds: DNPR) {}
}

enum PredicateType {
  STRING = "string"
}

export class DormEdge<AsArray extends boolean = false> {
  constructor(private predType: PredicateType, asArray: AsArray = false as AsArray) {}
}

const Audit = new DormNode({
  user: () => User
}) 

const User = new DormNode({
  name: new DormEdge(PredicateType.STRING),
  audits: () => Audit
});
```

My problem is that `Audit` and `User` are both inferred as type `any`. I need to be able to reference Audit from User so that I can reach a deep level of recursion such as: `Audit.preds.user().preds.audits()...`. Of course, this is just an example, my real-world use case is much more complex and deep. How can I fix this?

As a side note, on this part of the code:

```js
export class DormEdge<AsArray extends boolean = false> {...}
```

When I remove the `= false` from the generics, I am able to do what I intended to do. I don't exactly understand what is happening under the hood. I would appreciate if anyone could help me figure out the problem. For reference, I am using `typescript@5.3.3`. Thanks!

Comment: Your types are circular, and TS cannot always infer such types.  You will have to break or defer the circularity somehow. One way is to define explicitly recursive types and annotate them as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Wvo83w).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thank you for helping me! That makes sense, but frankly, TypeScript documentation doesn't make that clear (or maybe I haven't found the documentation for it yet). What you said answers the first question - I guess I still have to put more effort in maintaining types rather than managing them automatically. But my second question is still out there: why does removing `= false` work for some reason?

Comment: Stack Overflow posts are supposed to ask a single question, not multiple. I don’t mind looking into it but you shouldn’t make it a requirement to have that answered here.

Comment: I understand. I'll accept your first comment as the answer. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Sure, I'll write it up.  As for exactly why some code triggers the circularity warning and others don't, the only way to be sure is to walk through the compiler code when it's analyzing the types (or to file a github issue and have it triaged, possibly coming back as "not a defect" as in [ms/TS#49837](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49837)). There doesn't seem to be an existing GitHub issue that specifically refers to this problem (generic defaults making things worse where the default argument isn't itself self-referencing) but I expect it has to do with contextual typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript's type inference algorithm is heuristic in nature, and if it goes into a loop while trying to determine a type, it will give up with an implicit [`any`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any).  The heuristics work well for a wide range of real world code, dealing with "common" circularities.  But it can't work for everything, which would require a complete overhaul of the inference algorithm to implement *full [unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science))* as discussed in [microsoft/TypeScript#30134](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30134), and that is very unlikely to happen, because while it would be "correct" to do so, it would require an enormous amount of work, and probably result in a measurably worse IDE experience for a lot of common cases.

So sometimes there will be code that the compiler can't properly analyze because it hits a circularity.  To a human being it's often completely obvious how to decide the types and avoid such a circularity, but this doesn't really help with inference.  There are plenty of TypeScript GitHub issues where someone reports such a circularity as a bug, but the issue is marked as a design limitation or not a defect, with comments saying "this is the best we can do without spending more resources than we can afford".  For example, see [microsoft/TypeScript#49837](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49837#issuecomment-1179217420) or [microsoft/TypeScript#45213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45213#issuecomment-1016964197), or [microsoft/TypeScript#35546](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35546#issuecomment-1165685249).

In cases like this, the usual advice is to find a place where the compiler finds a circularity and [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) with an appropriate type.  That is, you *tell* the compiler what the type is, and it can go on to check it.  There are multiple ways to do that. In your case, it looks like there are truly recursive types involved, so you'd need to define them first:

```
type Audit = DormNode<{ user: () => User }>
type User = DormNode<{ name: DormEdge, audits: () => Audit }>;
```

And now you can annotate at least one of `Audit` and `User`, and it works:

```
const Audit: Audit = new DormNode({
  user: () => User
})
const User: User = new DormNode({
  name: new DormEdge(PredicateType.STRING),
  audits: () => Audit
});
```

Yes, this is more work for you than you'd like. Maybe there's some slightly less verbose annotation you can use, but no matter what there are going to be situations like this where the recommended approach is to [cut the knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordian_Knot) yourself instead of convincing the compiler to untie it.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAIg9gJwLYDk4BMIAUEXQSwGMBDYaAXlkSQFF0BzaAHygApWBKKcgPiuTSYAPPAEZsuAiTIAlCIUToeHANwBYAFD4AdmQQAzYoWijU4nHiKkIchQnRQA3pqhQA2gGsIIAFxQAzsAIOvQAun6mghKW0hDqGgC+mpoQAB5giMBQhAA2xP7+-GbCMChYMlBpZNrohZHmklay8op8zhquCtqBCACuhMCIrGC9AEY5RFBgkv4RZTJcjlBJickaENq9SFAWUtYAKuDQ7a4AyvsyAJIoAOLcUABEPSEPmisp6ZnZeQVFdIxCACC-kBCAQxBAlVS1VqUFGcDgOQgxG090MOX8EDaLmycG6QX6gwQw2CADdrFNJIdIH5dk0INSIAAaKD5UHg3xQYHsiFo4gY6D5LkgsEQxbLN5rUCQLm9AhZSj1YRLXqYhB+TjcPgAVTVyx4mml0F1EAQ9yVECES20xCQEAi1H+zNZcvwwFmbC4vFl8v18U0XUCPrdfkBroVUG0EAA7kUoqwTlBVaaNV6dWq3hwA3igyb1VA8-co7GLQmcTa7X5i38GBBWHTYoyAHTnK63DhMnHEcMezXesPyzMqIA)